# How assign popover to the nodes of the binary tree view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, binary-tree

I just created bootstrap popover mouse click to shows the binary tree nodes details.inside the popover contain  list items.I use setAttribute for pass the data to the nodes.But it's not working.I need to fix it.Here i included all the codes for your attention and for better sense what i'm trying to doing.Thank you

I created separate popover using button(not connected to the tree view).I saw that when i hover it data pass to the the popover menu properly.But i need to assign these data with popover to the node instead of button

Boostrap Popover

```
<div class="container">

        <a href="#" rel="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-popover-content="#list-popover">Show Popover</a>

        <div id="list-popover" class="hide">

                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li>
                        <label for="level">level:</label>
                        <input id="level" name="level" type="number" required>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="column">column :</label>
                        <input id="column" name="column" type="number" required>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="membershipNo">membershipNo :</label>
                        <input id="membershipNo" name="membershipNo" type="number" required>
                    </li>

                </ul>

                <div class="button">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" st>Close</button>
                </div>
        </div>
<script>

        $('[rel="popover"]').popover({
            container: 'body',
            trigger: 'id', 
            html: true,
            content: function () {
                var clone = $($(this).data('popover-content')).clone(true).removeClass('hide');
                return clone;
            }
        }).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>



    </div>

<div class="tree" >
        <ul>
            <li id="idl0cl1">
                <a href="#" id="aidl0cl1">Binary tree</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Code for generate tree nodes(this where popover assign to nodes)

```
 for (var y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
          val++;
     if (valuess[nm].column == val && valuess[nm].level == (x + 1)) {
            var node2 = document.createElement("LI");

            node2.setAttribute("id", "idl" + (x + 1) + "cl" + val);
            node2.setAttribute("class", "li");
            var node3 = document.createElement("A");


          node3.setAttribute("data-popover-content", "#list-popover");
          node3.setAttribute("class", "li");            
          node3.setAttribute("onclick", "mycall(" + valuess[nm].TreeId+")");

         node3.setAttribute("id", "aidl" + (x + 1) + "cl" + val);
         var textnode = document.createTextNode(valuess[nm].column);
         node3.appendChild(textnode);
         node2.appendChild(node3);
         node.appendChild(node2);
        document.getElementById("idl" + x + "cl" + (Math.round(val / 2))).appendChild(node);
         nm++;
         }
          else {
         }
       }
```